# Derivation of kinetic equation for fast particles in a plasma

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

Referring to Plasma Astrophysics, Part 1, author: Boris V Somov, 4.1.1,
We have the kinetic equation with Landau collisional integral,

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + v_{\alpha} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_{\alpha}} + \frac{q}{m} \left[ E_{\alpha} + \frac{1}{c} [ v \times \left( B + B_{0} \right) ]_{\alpha} \right] \frac{\partial f}{\partial v_{\alpha}} =  - \frac{\partial J_{\alpha}}{\partial v_{\alpha}}
$$

Assuming $E = 0, B = 0$ and $\partial f/ \partial t = 0$ and letting

$f = f(z,v,\theta)$ i.e. distribution function is only a function of coordinate z along magnetic field $B_0$, velocity $v$ and angle $\theta$ between $v$ and $z$ axis.

The kinetic equation becomes,

$$
v \cos{\theta} \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = - \frac{1}{v^{2}} \frac{ \partial \left( v^{2} J_{v} \right) }{\partial v}  - \frac{1}{v} \frac{1}{ \sin{\theta}} \frac{\partial \left( \sin{\theta} J_{\theta} \right) }{\partial \theta}
$$

How does this come about? The terms on the right-hand side look like divergence in spherical coordinates but here $f$ is defined in somewhat cylindrical coordinates (i.e. $z,v, \theta$).

Comment: I agree, this is a bit odd as the left-hand side is kind of cylindrical and right-hand side clearly spherical.  Both are scalars at this point, so it may be a matter of convenience for something that's done later.  The one problematic issue is that $\theta$ is defined as the azimuthal angle in cylindrical coordinates about the z-axis, not the angle between a vector and the z-axis...